# Apartment gem giving unexpected error when generating model on Rails 5.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, apartment-gem, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am new to rails platform. I'm building a multi-tenant application using **Apartment gem**. I'm following https://medium.com/@balogic/using-apartment-gem-to-implement-multitenant-concept-in-rails-b86f7d9e37c5 this guide to learn how to use this gem. But when i am scaffolding or generating User model i am getting the below error :

`` $ rails g scaffold Users email name subdomain
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.0/lib/action                                                                     _dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in `build': undefined method `new' for "Apartme                                                                     nt::Elevators::Subdomain":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  next
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1                                                                     .0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `block in build'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1                                                                     .0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1                                                                     .0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `inject'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1                                                                     .0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `build'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/engine.rb:508:in `block in app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:45:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block i                                                                     n tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (                                                                     2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_st                                                                     rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block i                                                                     n each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_st                                                                     rongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_e                                                                     ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_e                                                                     ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Sites/multitenant_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required                                                                     )>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/command/actions.rb:16:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:19:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li                                                                     b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li                                                                     b/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li                                                                     b/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0                                                                     /lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>' ``

**Note : ** My Rails version is 5.0.1 and Ruby version is 2.3.0

Comment: what is the content of `config/initializers/apartment.rb`?

Comment: @rony36 Content of config/initializers/apartment.rb is https://gist.github.com/vinayshetty0592/852e8a32c9140405cef489db04d63e2b

Answer (score 4):

Change this line `Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain'` removing quotation marks.

Reference:
https://github.com/influitive/apartment/pull/422

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in application.rb file

```
require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'
```

Add below line in application.rb file inside Application class

```
config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
```

Comment: you can add your custom elevators and find tenant based on your criteria